# class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass): invalid syntax for docker-compose up command

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker-compose, yaml, pyyaml

On my Linux system two python versions are present 2.7 and 3.6. To use python 3.6. in my PYTHONPATH in .profile file I have kept /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages and /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages at the top. and there is no entry of python 2.7 path. In my sys.path variable I can see the python2.7 path entries. (dont know how they appear)
now the issue is when I use docker-compose up command it gives me below error. docker-compose version is 1.29.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ..bundle import get_image_digests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/bundle.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .config.serialize import denormalize_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 13, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 284
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I add python 2.7 site package path at the top of PYTHONPATH docker-compose works but other programs start failing. I dont want to use python 2.7 how can I use only python 3.6.

Please suggest.